# Allocating with malloc in Cython

Tags: cython

Is there any difference in Cython between allocating memory like this

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc
cdef int *ar = <int *>malloc(100 * sizeof(int))
```

and like this

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc
ar = <int *>malloc(100 * sizeof(int))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No difference. The latter just relies on Cython's ability to deduce the type of `ar`, which should be pretty easy in this case. If the type deduction fails then you'd get an error message at the cythonizing stage.